# Why one tuple list is being printed with quotes and another tuple without?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am creating two tuple lists :

The first one is :

```
Entity=tuple(df['Entity'])
```

and the output is this

```
(1007897079, 1007897253, 1007898597)`
```

The other one is :

```
Research=tuple(df8['research'])
```

and the output is

```
('2008841156', '1432883725', '2000535429')
```

Why is the second one with quotes ? Can i remove them ?
Thanks a lot!

I have tried to remove the quotes but it seems like i can't do it. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Because one of the dataframes contains numbers, the other contains strings.

Comment: `tuple(map(int, df8['research']))`

Comment: Please read and follow [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/235698)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column types are different.  Reproducible example and fix:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'entity': [1007897079, 1007897253, 1007898597],           # integers
                   'research': ['2008841156', '1432883725', '2000535429']})  # strings
print(df)
print('entity', tuple(df.entity))
print('research', tuple(df.research))
print('research(forced)', tuple(df.research.astype(int)))  # force integers
df.research = df.research.astype(int)  # convert the column
print('research(converted)', tuple(df.research))
```

Output:

```
       entity    research
0  1007897079  2008841156
1  1007897253  1432883725
2  1007898597  2000535429
entity (1007897079, 1007897253, 1007898597)
research ('2008841156', '1432883725', '2000535429')
research(forced) (2008841156, 1432883725, 2000535429)
research(converted) (2008841156, 1432883725, 2000535429)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation!